# Yellow triangle in data sources Windows

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Does any one know what it means when in the visual studio data sources Windows all the tables of a dataset show a yellow triangle containing an exclamation mark next to it?  I have googled like hell but can't find an answer anywhere

Comment: Can you provide any further information about the warnings you get? Are the warnings still there if you re-add the Data Source?